# marshmallow trouble with internal storage

Tags: storage

i have galaxy on5 device. its updated to marshmallow on last week but after update it start performing some error. biggest problem is with storage. in internal storage it showing 7.3 gb used but actually it used only 5.4gb. because of showing 7.3 gb used out of 8gb i uninstall some big apps but still it showing 7.3gb used only. actually i having same problem with my sd card but i just unmount my sd card and again mount it, then it shows the correct space used.
kindly tell me how to troubleshoot this problem.
email: shubhamhunter.swami@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning the cache? There might be junk folders and files you can delete also. Don't forget moving all movable apps in the SD Card. I would recommend you install ES File Explorer on Google play to clean your storage.